# How do I access http request using Streams in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

So I have created a node.js server and placed JSON file there which looks like this:

```
  [ 
   { 
      "name": "iPhone", 
      "description": "iPhone is the stylist phone ever", 
      "price": 1000, 
      "image": "iphone.png" 
   }, 
   { 
      "name": "Pixel", 
      "description": "Pixel is the most feature phone ever", 
      "price": 800, 
      "image": "pixel.png"
   }, 
   { 
      "name": "Laptop", 
      "description": "Laptop is most productive development tool", 
      "price": 2000, 
      "image": "laptop.png" 
   }, 
   { 
      "name": "Tablet", 
      "description": "Tablet is the most useful device ever for meeting", 
      "price": 1500, 
      "image": "tablet.png" 
   }, 
   { 
      "name": "Pendrive", 
      "description": "Pendrive is useful storage medium", 
      "price": 100, 
      "image": "pendrive.png" 
   }, 
]
```

I have connected my Dart script to the JSON using http package.

```
  void getData() async {
  var data = await http.get('http://192.168.43.18:8080/products.json');

  var myData = jsonDecode(data.body);
  print(myData);
}
```

Everything works fine but,
I want to see changes in my console when data is updated in the JSON file, using Streams, How can I do that? Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: you mean [stream](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/StreamedResponse/stream.html) property?

Comment: yes, the stream property.

Comment: How about consider using [StreamBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkKEWHfy99Y), and [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). And head to [this tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=using+streambuilder+and+firestore+in+flutter&rlz=1CAQUPU_enPH893&oq=using+streambuilder+and+firestore+in+flutter&aqs=chrome..69i57j33l2.10591j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_jyHCXv2fAZL6wQPe2ZTIDQ34) for an in depth discussion?